# Adding multiple timestamp to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an attendance management system in which I want to store punch in time and punch out time as timestamp in database. The query for the table is as shown:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punchdetails` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`employeeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`punchin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`punchout` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`SERVER_ADDRIN` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`REMOTE_ADDRIN` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`REQUEST_TIMEIN` int(30) NOT NULL,
`SERVER_ADDROUT` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`REMOTE_ADDROUT` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`REQUEST_TIMEOUT` int(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When the employee is logged in to the system at the first time for that day, he will have **Punch In** option to punchin for the day. Then the field *punchin* should be populated with current timestamp and *punchout* field should be null only. The value for punch out should be inserted only when clicking on **Punch Out** link.

But now when I am trying to insert value to only *punchin*, both *punchin* and *punchout* are getting inserted.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: maybe you should also post your query code

Comment: Fields are only updated if they are included in your query.

Comment: Try null instead of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Also why do you want to update the punchin timestamp? That way punchin and punchout will be the same in the end.

Comment: I tried by executing the query                                    'INSERT INTO punchdetails(punchin) VALUES(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())'. But both the values are getting inserted as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) is just as good, but you shouldn't have to mention the timestamp col name anyway.

Comment: Jonast92 at first login for the day, employee will have only the option to punchin. At that time punchin field should be updated with current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
`punchin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`punchout` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Comment: But then each time punchin field will get updated by current timestamp right? But I want only punchout field to be updated each time. Once value is inserted into punchin, it shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose field type as timestamp, Current time will get added into the field. So in your case, Both Punchin & Punchout will fill with same value. So change type for punchout as mentioned by @jaczes